# securitymanager.policyhierarchy() is obsolete, what is its replacement?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

SecurityManager.PolicyHierarchy() produces a warning about being obsolete, but I am unable to find what method it is replaced by or how to replace it when used to compare received and present policy levels.

E.g.

```
SecEnumerator levelEnumerator = SecurityManager.PolicyHierarchy();
while (levelEnumerator.MoveNext())
{
 PolicyLevel Seclevel = levelEnumerator.Current as PolicyLevel;
 if (Seclevel == Init.Seclevel)
 {
      return;
 }
}
```

For such an application what other method should be used now?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and provide a [mcve] incl. **full** _run-time exception_ as well as _compile-time warning_. The latter could offer a _suggested alternate API_.

Comment: I can't give you an answer, I have not worked with this part of .NET but from 

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnfa/2009/06/09/coding-with-security-policy-in-net-4-part-2-explicit-uses-of-cas-policy/

I understand there might not be a direct replacement, but maybe one of those code samples does what you need.

Answer (score 4):

There is no replacement.

As you can see in the documentation page of `SecurityManager` in MSDN, all and every method related to policies are obsolete. The reason for that is the fact that Policies are now removed from CAS (well, since .Net4). To read more about this check here:

[Summary of Changes in Code Access Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ff527276(v=vs.110))

That being said, in the description of this warning there is a good link that provides you with the necessary information required to change your code and suggest possible alternatives:

[Code Access Security Policy Compatibility and Migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ee191568(v=vs.100))

[Migration: Replacement for Obsolete Calls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ee191568(v=vs.100)#migration-replacement-for-obsolete-calls)

To help you better we need to know what you are exactly trying to achieve here. Describe your goal and we might be able to suggest an alternate or replacement.

---

Based on your comment it seems that what you are trying to do is to sandbox a piece of user-inserted code (as you put it) and limit its access. This is not the what CAS should be used for. In fact, there is a clear warning about this type of usages in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/code-access-security-policy-compatibility-and-migration):

> Code Access Security in .NET Framework should not be used as a
>   mechanism for enforcing security boundaries based on code origination
>   or other identity aspects.

Your code probably should be refactored in a way to retrieve the permissions required by a piece of code using the provided `Evidence` (being strong name or url, etc) by the [`SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(Evidence)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.securitymanager.getstandardsandbox?view=netframework-4.7.2) method and then use the returned permissions to load the assembly in a new sandboxed AppDomain using the [`CreateDomain(String, Evidence, AppDomainSetup, PermissionSet, StrongName[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.createdomain?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_AppDomain_CreateDomain_System_String_System_Security_Policy_Evidence_System_AppDomainSetup_System_Security_PermissionSet_System_Security_Policy_StrongName___) method. You can also change these permissions before creating a new domain to have more control over the execution of the code. Following article can help you refactor your application:

[How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox)

In other words, there are no policies anymore, but you can define, retrieve and execute your code under a specific [`PermissionSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.permissionset?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: The return of the code is used to determine whether a use-inserted piece of code shall be allowed to execute on the system. The user-inserted code is evaluated and the highest needed policy is determined, the code above then determines if that policy level exists and allows the execution. If there are no more policy levels the whole system may actually be broken now.

Comment: @user2280032, I just added additional information regarding your use case.